# How to access variables outside stages in Jenkins file Groovy function?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins file looks like below:

```
import groovy.json.*
def manifestFile = "C:\\manifest.yml"

node {
  stage('Build') { 

  }
  stage('Deploy') { 
    checkDeployStatus()
  } 
}

def boolean checkDeployStatus() {
  echo "${manifestFile}"
  return true
}
```

The exception that i am getting is below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manifestFile for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

How do i access variables outside the node?

Comment: For whom lands here, check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571316/strange-variable-scoping-behavior-in-jenkinsfile

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Groovy has a different kind of scoping at the script level. I can't ever keep it all sorted in my head. Without trying explain all the reasons for it (and probably not doing it justice), I can tell you that (as you have seen), the `manifestFile` variable is not in scope in that function. Just don't declare the `manifestFile` (i.e. don't put `def` in front of it). That will make it a "global" (not really, but for your purposes here) variable, then it should be accessible in the method call.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
import groovy.json.*
manifestFile = "C:\\manifest.yml"

node {
  stage('Build') { 

  }
  stage('Deploy') { 
    checkDeployStatus()
  } 
}

def boolean checkDeployStatus() {
  echo "${manifestFile}"
  return true
}
```

Comment: Be aware there are some potential issues with this approach. It's recommend to annotate the variable with `@Field` if you want to change the scope. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50573082/6405287)