# Strange variable scoping behavior in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

When I run the below Jenkins pipeline script:

```
def some_var = "some value"

def pr() {
    def another_var = "another " + some_var
    echo "${another_var}"
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ("Run") {
            steps {
                pr()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: some_var for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

If the `def` is removed from `some_var`, it works fine. Could someone explain the scoping rules that cause this behavior?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

### TL;DR

- variables defined **with** `def` in the main script body cannot be accessed from other methods.
- variables defined **without** `def` can be accessed directly by any method even from different scripts. It's a bad practice.
- variables defined **with** `def` **and** [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html)  annotation can be accessed directly from methods defined in the same script.

### Explanation

When groovy compiles that script it actually moves everything to a class that **roughly** looks something like this

```
class Script1 {
    def pr() {
        def another_var = "another " + some_var
        echo "${another_var}"
    }
    def run() {
        def some_var = "some value"
        pipeline {
            agent any
            stages {
                stage ("Run") {
                    steps {
                        pr()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that `some_var` is clearly out of scope for `pr()` becuse it's a local variable in a different method.

When you define a variable **without** `def` you actually put that variable into a [Binding](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) of the script (so-called *binding variables*). So when groovy executes `pr()` method firstly it tries to find a local variable with a name `some_var` and if it doesn't exist it then tries to find that variable in a Binding (which exists because you defined it without `def`).

Binding variables are considered bad practice because if you load multiple scripts (`load` step) binding variables will be accessible in all those scripts because Jenkins shares the same Binding for all scripts. A much better alternative is to use [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) annotation. This way you can make a variable accessible in all methods inside one script without exposing it to other scripts.

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field 
def some_var = "some value"

def pr() {
    def another_var = "another " + some_var
    echo "${another_var}"
}
//your pipeline
```

When groovy compiles this script into a class it will look something like this

```
class Script1 {
    def some_var = "some value"

    def pr() {
        def another_var = "another " + some_var
        echo "${another_var}"
    }
    def run() {
        //your pipeline
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation with visualization of the generated script. Also thanks for the suggestion on `@Field`. Your answer goes beyond my expectations!

Comment: Great Answer, Will declaring variable (with{out} def and @field) inside parallel stages has any access limitation from one stage to another stage? How the visibility of variables declared inside the stages/steps in pipeline script?

Comment: Also kindly explain the scope/accessibility of variable declared inside the environment block, and how it is equivalent to java class variables ?

Comment: how would you scope a variable local to a stage, such that its available in the post step of that stage as well?

Comment: is this true for libraries that my pipeline steps may call also.  if i have a custom library that i load, would functions called in that library be able to access 'some_var' if it was decleared with @FIELD?

Answer (score 9):

Great Answer from @Vitalii Vitrenko! 
I tried program to verify that. Also added few more test cases.

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field  
def CLASS_VAR = "CLASS"
def METHOD_VAR = "METHOD"
GLOBAL_VAR = "GLOBAL"

def testMethod() {
    echo  "testMethod starts:" 
    def testMethodLocalVar = "Test_Method_Local_Var"
    testMethodGlobalVar = "Test_Metho_Global_var"
    echo "${CLASS_VAR}"
    // echo "${METHOD_VAR}" //can be accessed only within pipeline run method
    echo "${GLOBAL_VAR}"
    echo "${testMethodLocalVar}"
    echo "${testMethodGlobalVar}"
    echo  "testMethod ends:" 
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('parallel stage') {
             parallel {
                 stage('parallel one') {
                     agent any
                     steps {
                        echo  "parallel one" 
                        testMethod()
                        echo "${CLASS_VAR}"
                        echo "${METHOD_VAR}"
                        echo "${GLOBAL_VAR}"
                        echo "${testMethodGlobalVar}"
                        script {
                            pipelineMethodOneGlobalVar = "pipelineMethodOneGlobalVar"
                            sh_output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'pwd' //Declared global to access outside the script
                        }
                        echo "sh_output ${sh_output}"
                     }
                 }
                 stage('parallel two') {
                     agent any
                     steps {
                         echo  "parallel two"
                        //  pipelineGlobalVar = "new"      //cannot introduce new variables here
                        //  def pipelineMethodVar = "new"  //cannot introduce new variables here
                         script { //new variable and reassigning needs scripted-pipeline
                             def pipelineMethodLocalVar = "new";
                             pipelineMethodLocalVar = "pipelineMethodLocalVar reassigned";
                             pipelineMethodGlobalVar = "new" //no def keyword
                             pipelineMethodGlobalVar = "pipelineMethodGlobalVar reassigned"

                             CLASS_VAR = "CLASS TWO"
                             METHOD_VAR = "METHOD TWO"
                             GLOBAL_VAR = "GLOBAL TWO"
                         }
                        //  echo "${pipelineMethodLocalVar}" only script level scope, cannot be accessed here
                         echo "${pipelineMethodGlobalVar}"
                         echo "${pipelineMethodOneGlobalVar}"
                         testMethod()
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         stage('sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "sequential"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Observations:

1. Six cases of variables declarations

   a. Three types (with def, without def, with def and with @field) before/above pipeline

   b. within scripted-pipeline (with def, without def) within pipeline

   c. Local to a method (with def) outside pipeline
2. new variable declaration and reassigning needs scripted-pipeline within pipeline.
3. All the variable declared outside pipeline can be accessed between the stages
4. Variable with def keyword generally specific to a method, if it is declared inside script then will not be available outside of it. So need to declare global variable (without def) within script to access outside of script.

Comment: Thank you, also great addition!
In my case Jenkins throws when using @Field. I've passed a variable with `def` from pipeline to an external method.