# Jenkins pipeline replaces method call in vars/mavenBuildSpike.groovy with assignment "new NullObject"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this code in `vars/mavenBuildSpike.groovy`:

```
@NonCPS
def createSqBuilder(SqBuildConfig config) {
    System.out.println("createSqBuilder=${config}")
    // The constructor contains code which the CPS transformer can't handle.
    def result = new SqBuilder(config)
    System.out.println("result=${result}")
    return result
}

def call(Closure body) {

    echo 'Creating ConfigBuilderWrapper'
    def wrapper = new ConfigBuilderWrapper()
    echo 'Calling apply()'
    wrapper.apply(body)
    echo 'Done processing closure'

    def config = wrapper.builder.build()
    echo "config=${config.dump()}"

    echo 'Creating builder'
    def builder = createSqBuilder(config)    // <<--- This doesn't work.
    echo "builder=${builder}"

    echo builder.dump()
    ...
```

The output is:

```
...everything looks good...
[Pipeline] echo
Creating builder
[Pipeline] echo
builder=null
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method hashCode() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.hashCode(NullObject.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.dump(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:291)
    ...
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at mavenBuildSpike.call(...\branches\master\builds\16\libs\sq-pipeline-library-spike\vars\mavenBuildSpike.groovy:33)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:4)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    ....
```

That is, the method `createSqBuilder` is never called and just replaced with an assignment: `def builder = new NullObject()`.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: While I am not completely sure what is wrong about your syntax/usage, in general those kind of utility/helper methods that are invoked from the global var in a shared library are defined inside src within a package and then imported in a global var for usage. That definitely works.

Comment: @MattSchuchard How do I define a global variable in `vars/mavenBuildSpike.groovy`? And how "global" is it? Shared between all Jenkins jobs or just global for the single job?

Comment: In Jenkins Pipeline, in general everything defined within `vars/*.groovy` in a shared library is a global var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the code, Jenkins will do an AST transformation called "CPS transformation". This transformer doesn't support everything that Groovy can do and it won't tell you when it can't - you'll just get weird or useless error messages running the resulting code and sometimes no errors at all - the build will simply fail without any error message or stack trace anywhere.

It seems that the CPS transform doesn't like calling constructors with arguments. This worked for me:

```
@Field // groovy.transform.Field
SqBuilder builder = new SqBuilder()

def call(Closure body) {
    ...
    //def builder = createSqBuilder(config)  // Doesn't work!!!
    builder.init(config) // This works; move the code from the constructor to the init() method.
    ...
```

The `@Field` annotation is necessary to turn the local variable `builder` into a field of the class which Groovy will create at runtime. The name of this class is `WorkflowScript`.

You could also just type `builder = new SqBuilder()` (without type or `def` before the variable name). But that would put `builder` into the pool of global variables (called "Binding" in Groovy). Jenkins puts it's own stuff there (like `env` or `scm`) so that could cause strange problems when you install more plugins.

See also: [Strange variable scoping behavior in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571316/strange-variable-scoping-behavior-in-jenkinsfile)