# Jenkins - disable stop / cancel for single stage

Tags: jenkins, devops

In a groovy multi-branch pipeline on Jenkins I have a single step which I don't want any user to be able to abort via the UI. However any other step should be able to be aborted. See example pipeline definition:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {
    stage("I can be aborted") {
      // run some scripts etc here
    }

    stage("I cannot be aborted") {
      // some code that will complete even if stop / abort is pressed
    }

    stage("I will run if the build was not stopped before and can be stopped") {
      // rest of the pipeline
    }

}
```

TLDR;
block the ability to stop a jenkins build on a per stage basis

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

When a user aborts a build, the code being execution usually throws an [AbortException](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/AbortException.html) although it can also throw an [InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) (I've seen that where a stage is aborted while executing a shell script).

Since your pipeline is in groovy, you can use `try/catch` blocks to get the behavior you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.transform.Field // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50573082/6692227

@Field boolean stopBuild = false

node {
    stage("I can be aborted") {
      // run some scripts etc here
    }

    stage("I cannot be aborted") {
      try {
        // some code that will complete even if stop / abort is pressed
      } catch (AbortException ex) {
        currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE" // or whatever
        echo "User tried to abort but that's not allowed"
        stopBuild = true
      }
    }

    stage("I will run if the build was not stopped before and can be stopped") {
      if (stopBuild) return

      // rest of the pipeline
    }

}
```

Comment: How would this work? - if I have 3 lines of code in the try block and the user stops the build on the second line (lets say it's a sleep for 10s), the third line will not get executed.

Comment: @bill-166 The idea is the same. Every line you want executed you'll have to make sure is preceded by a block in a `try/catch`.

Comment: That won't work if the user presses 'abort' while a long-running step is executed.