# String variable assignment does not include string reference in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building a scripted Jenkinsfile (written in Groovy, which I do not know all that well -- nor do I know Java for that matter)

I have a particular string variable that for some reason doesn't want to behave properly and I'm perplexed.

```java
import groovy.transform.Field
// THIS WORKS
@Field def FOO = "Mary had a little lamb"
@Field def BAR = "whose fleece was white as snow"
@Field def FOOBAR = "${FOO} ${BAR}"
echo "FOOBAR: ${FOOBAR}"
echo "FOO & BAR: ${FOO} ${BAR}"
```

results as you would expect

```
[Pipeline] echo
FOOBAR: Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow
[Pipeline] echo
FOO & BAR: Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow
```

However, the following:

```java
// THIS DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED
@Field def BAR = "and she murdered it"
@Field def FOO = "Mary had a little lamb"
if (FOO) {
    BAR = "whose fleece was white as snow"
}
@Field def FOOBAR = "${FOO} ${BAR}"
echo "FOOBAR: ${FOOBAR}"
echo "FOO & BAR: ${FOO} ${BAR}"
```

results

```
[Pipeline] echo
FOOBAR: Mary had a little lamb and she murdered it
[Pipeline] echo
FOO & BAR: Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow
```

Is there some nuance to order of events in Java/Groovy that I'm not understanding?  (I'm a python guy) 
`BAR` is overwritten but it would appear when defining the variable `FOOBAR`, it uses the original value for `BAR` whereas when simply building the string in the echo statement it uses the new value for `BAR`.  What?!
Or is this a nuance with how Jenkins is working in conjunction with Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a Groovy script, groovy effectively wraps your script in a standard java class, inside a method `run()`

So if we remove the `@Field` annotations, the script:

```
def FOO = "Mary had a little lamb"
def BAR = "whose fleece was white as snow"
def FOOBAR = "${FOO} ${BAR}"
echo "FOOBAR: ${FOOBAR}"
echo "FOO & BAR: ${FOO} ${BAR}"
```

Becomes effectively:

```
public class script1582564680906 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        java.lang.Object FOO = 'Mary had a little lamb'
        java.lang.Object BAR = 'whose fleece was white as snow'
        java.lang.Object FOOBAR = "$FOO $BAR"
        this.echo("FOOBAR: $FOOBAR")
        this.echo("FOO & BAR: $FOO $BAR")
    }

}
```

Plus some other stuff that isn't important for this question...  This is fine, but if you add a method to your script, like so:

```
def something() {
    FOO = 'tim'
}

def FOO = "Mary had a little lamb"
def BAR = "whose fleece was white as snow"
def FOOBAR = "${FOO} ${BAR}"
echo "FOOBAR: ${FOOBAR}"
echo "FOO & BAR: ${FOO} ${BAR}"
```

The class becomes:

```
public class script1582564855552 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        java.lang.Object FOO = 'Mary had a little lamb'
        java.lang.Object BAR = 'whose fleece was white as snow'
        java.lang.Object FOOBAR = "$FOO $BAR"
        this.echo("FOOBAR: $FOOBAR")
        this.echo("FOO & BAR: $FOO $BAR")
    }

    public java.lang.Object something() {
        FOO = 'tim'
    }

}
```

As you can see, in my `something()` method, I'm trying to access `FOO`, but this is only valid inside the `run()` method.

This is why the `@Field` annotation exists.  It tells Groovy to move the definition up to class level instead of inside `run()`, so this:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def FOO = "Mary had a little lamb"
@Field def BAR = "whose fleece was white as snow"
@Field def FOOBAR = "${FOO} ${BAR}"
echo "FOOBAR: ${FOOBAR}"
echo "FOO & BAR: ${FOO} ${BAR}"
```

Becomes this:

```
public class script1582565001609 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    java.lang.Object FOO = 'Mary had a little lamb'
    java.lang.Object BAR = 'whose fleece was white as snow'
    java.lang.Object FOOBAR = "$FOO $BAR"

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        this.echo("FOOBAR: $FOOBAR")
        this.echo("FOO & BAR: $FOO $BAR")
    }

}
```

So now we get to your question...  Taking this:

```
@Field def BAR = "and she murdered it"
@Field def FOO = "Mary had a little lamb"
if (FOO) {
    BAR = "whose fleece was white as snow"
}
@Field def FOOBAR = "${FOO} ${BAR}"
echo "FOOBAR: ${FOOBAR}"
echo "FOO & BAR: ${FOO} ${BAR}"
```

And converting it following the above rules gives us:

```
public class script1582565140864 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    java.lang.Object BAR = 'and she murdered it'
    java.lang.Object FOO = 'Mary had a little lamb'
    java.lang.Object FOOBAR = "$FOO $BAR"

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        if ( FOO ) {
            BAR = 'whose fleece was white as snow'
        }
        this.echo("FOOBAR: $FOOBAR")
        return this.echo("FOO & BAR: $FOO $BAR")
    }
}
```

As you can see...  `FOOBAR` is set up as a field, so it initialised way before you modify `BAR` to be `'whose fleece was white as snow'`

But FOO and BAR are as you'd expect when you debug them...

Avoid `@Field` if you can get away with it, as it makes things hard to reason about

Comment: Excellent explanation!  I have been using `@Field` based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50573082/2532408. I wanted the variables to be 'global' but only at the script level.  I see now why I was confused about how this is actually working.  I think my solution will be to 'initialize' FOOBAR to an empty string followed by reassigning the variable.